# Bypassing DNS requests app-wise in iOS

Tags: ios, dns, nsurlconnection, objective-c-category

I know that I can't permanently set DNS servers programmatically on a non-jailbroken device, but I'm searching for a method to route all DNS requests in my app to a specified DNS server (e.g. Google DNS 4.2.2.1) in order to bypass DNS-based government censoring. I know I can hard-code specified IP addresses to hosts by setting IP and host header in an NSURLRequest (I'm already doing that in another app), but I'm looking for a more general way to achieve this. Is there any way to redirect all DNS requests in my app? Would category-overriding NSURLConnection's methods (I know in general it's a very bad practice, but it would work beautifully in my app) allow me to override default behavior of URL requests? Does it involve accessing/overriding (if possible) private APIs and cause my app to be rejected from App Store? What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

If your app will operate in an environment where they can reach your desired IP address, but cannot trust DNS, then you could hard-code the app to use the target, and then add a "failover server" pre-loader, which you send if you plan to move IP address.

When you move, you also should release an update that has the new addresses in the new version.

There are a lot of limitations to this approach... and I think the larger network assumptions might not make sense (if they are blocking DNS, it seems unlikely you will be able to have good connectivity to your IP addresses.)

The only reason I suggest this is that the iOS update mechanism makes it seem remotely usable. For more traditional software, I would have kept quiet.